# Excel Formula Help Conditional Formatting - If A2 =TODAY and B2=Y turn A2 Green. If B2 = N turn A2 RED

Tags: excel-formula

Just after some help to make a formula based on two formulas having certain conditions to highlight a Green or Red outcome. It will depend on the TODAY() and turn A2 Green or Red depending if B2 is Y/N.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a conditional format rule on A2 which says:

```
=AND(A2=TODAY(),B2="Y")
```

If *both of* A2 equals today, and B2 equals "Y", then this will say TRUE. When a conditional formatting rule says TRUE, the rule applies. So, make your rule here highlight Green. Put the normal highlighting as Red, and then the Red will be overridden if the conditional format applies.

Comment: Or leave it non-highlighted and add a second conditional rule of `=B2="N"` then highlight red. That way it will not always be red if blank or a different value.